# dash, python, inserting data to dash table

Tags: python, callback, dashboard

please I really need help. I need to write callbacks for apply and clear buttons for material selection tool.  I select material frop dropdown and click apply, it will insert that value to the Material column of the table according to the active cell. If I click clear it will clear that row of Material column according to the active cell. Please help me I could not do, I am new to dash.

```
import dash
from dash import dcc, html, Input, Output,State
import dash_table
import pandas as pd
import io
import base64

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

#Create a default DataFrame with the desired columns and a single row
default_data = [{'Name': '', 'Size': '', 'Material': '', 'Fixed': '', 'Tree Info': ''}]
default_columns = [{'name': col, 'id': col} for col in default_data[0].keys()]

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        dcc.Upload(
            id='upload-data',
            children=html.Div([
                html.P('Select a file.', style={'margin': 0}),
            ]),
            style={
                'width': '75%',
                'height': '45px',
                'lineHeight': '40px',
                'borderStyle': 'solid',
                'borderWidth': '1px',
                'borderRadius': '1px',
                'borderColor': 'gray',
                'textAlign': 'center',
                'margin': '10px',
                'cursor': 'pointer',
                'background-color': '#f0f0f0',
            },
            multiple=False
        ),
        html.Button('Cancel', id='cancel-button', disabled=True,
                    style={'width': '75%',
                           'cursor': 'pointer',
                           'border': 'none',
                           'margin-left': '10px',
                           'border-radius': '1px',
                           'background-color': '#f0f0f0',
                           'color': 'gray'}),
        
        html.Div([
            html.Button('Tick Selected Rows', id='button-1',
                        style={'width': '75%',
                               'margin-top': '30px',
                               'lineHeight': '30px',
                               'borderStyle': 'solid',
                               'borderWidth': '1px',
                               'borderRadius': '1px',
                               'borderColor': 'gray',
                               'textAlign': 'center',
                               'margin': '10px',
                               'cursor': 'pointer',
                               'background-color': '#f0f0f0'}),
            html.Button('Untick Selected Rows', id='button-2',
                        style={'width': '75%',
                               'margin-top': '5px',
                               'lineHeight': '30px',
                               'borderStyle': 'solid',
                               'borderWidth': '1px',
                               'borderRadius': '1px',
                               'borderColor': 'gray',
                               'textAlign': 'center',
                               'margin': '10px',
                               'cursor': 'pointer',
                               'background-color': '#f0f0f0'})
        ], style={'float': 'down', 'width': '100%'}),
        
        html.Div([
            html.P("Material Selection Tool", className="simple-text", style={'margin-left': '20px'}),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='material-selection',
                options=[
                    {'label': 'AL5052', 'value': 'AL5052'},
                    {'label': "Pc", 'value': 'Pc'},
                    {'label': "Glass", 'value': 'Glass'},
                    {'label': "Tape", 'value': 'Tape'}
                ],
                placeholder='Select a material.',
                style={'width': '90%'}
            ),
            html.Button('Apply', id='apply-button',n_clicks=0,
                        style={'width': '75%',
                               'margin-top': '2px',
                               'lineHeight': '20px',
                               'borderStyle': 'solid',
                               'borderWidth': '1px',
                               'borderRadius': '1px',
                               'borderColor': 'gray',
                               'textAlign': 'center',
                               'margin': '10px',
                               'cursor': 'pointer',
                               'background-color': '#f0f0f0'}),
            html.Button('Clear', id='clear-button', n_clicks=0,
                        style={'width': '75%',
                               'margin-top': '2px',
                               'lineHeight': '20px',
                               'borderStyle': 'solid',
                               'borderWidth': '1px',
                               'borderRadius': '1px',
                               'borderColor': 'gray',
                               'textAlign': 'center',
                               'margin': '10px',
                               'cursor': 'pointer',
                               'background-color': '#f0f0f0'}
                       )
        ], style={'float': 'down', 'width': '100%'}),
        
        html.Div([
            html.P("Fixed Condition Selection Tool", className="simple-text", style={'margin-left': '20px'}),
            html.Button('Apply', id='apply-button-fix',n_clicks=0,
                        style={'width': '75%',
                               'margin-top': '2px',
                               'lineHeight': '20px',
                               'borderStyle': 'solid',
                               'borderWidth': '1px',
                               'borderRadius': '1px',
                               'borderColor': 'gray',
                               'textAlign': 'center',
                               'margin': '10px',
                               'cursor': 'pointer',
                               'background-color': '#f0f0f0'}),
            html.Button('Clear', id='clear-button-fix', n_clicks=0,
                        style={'width': '75%',
                               'margin-top': '2px',
                               'lineHeight': '20px',
                               'borderStyle': 'solid',
                               'borderWidth': '1px',
                               'borderRadius': '1px',
                               'borderColor': 'gray',
                               'textAlign': 'center',
                               'margin': '10px',
                               'cursor': 'pointer',
                               'background-color': '#f0f0f0'}
                       )
        ], style={'float': 'down', 'width': '100%'}),
        
    ], style={'float': 'left', 'width': '40%'}),
    
    html.Div([ dash_table.DataTable(id='datatable-upload', style_table={'height': '600px'},
                             data=default_data,
                             columns=default_columns,
                             style_header={'fontWeight': 'bold', 'textAlign': 'center'},
                             editable=True,
                             filter_action="native",
                             sort_action="native",
                             sort_mode="single",
                             column_selectable="multi",
                             row_selectable="multi",
                             row_deletable=False,
                             selected_columns=[],
                             selected_rows=[],
                             page_action="native",
                             page_current=0,
                             style_cell={
                                 'minWidth': 95, 'maxWidth': 95, 'width': 95
                             },
                             style_cell_conditional=[
                                 {
                                     'if': {'column_id': c},
                                     'textAlign': 'left'
                                 } for c in ['country', 'iso_alpha3']
                             ],
                             style_data={
                                 'whiteSpace': 'normal',
                                 'height': 'auto'
                             }
                             ),
    ], style={'float': 'left', 'width': '100%'}),
], style={'width': '100%', 'overflow': 'auto', 'display': 'flex'})
```

This is my layout, now I will share my other callbacks.

```
#callback for tick and untick buttons
@app.callback(
    Output('datatable-upload', 'selected_rows'),
    Input('button-1', 'n_clicks'),
    Input('button-2', 'n_clicks'),
    State('datatable-upload', 'active_cell'),
    State('datatable-upload', 'selected_rows'),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def update_selected_rows(button_1_clicks, button_2_clicks, active_cell, selected_rows):
    ctx = dash.callback_context

    if not ctx.triggered:
        return selected_rows

    trigger_id = ctx.triggered[0]['prop_id'].split('.')[0]

    if trigger_id == 'button-1':
        if active_cell and active_cell['row'] not in selected_rows:
            selected_rows.append(active_cell['row'])
        return selected_rows
    elif trigger_id == 'button-2':
        if active_cell and active_cell['row'] in selected_rows:
            selected_rows.remove(active_cell['row'])
        return selected_rows
    else:
        return selected_rows
    

#callback for drag and cancel buttons. 
@app.callback(
    Output('datatable-upload', 'data'),
    Output('datatable-upload', 'columns'),
    Output('cancel-button', 'disabled'),
    Output('cancel-button', 'style'),
    Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
    Input('cancel-button', 'n_clicks'),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def update_output(contents, n_clicks):
    if contents is None:
        return default_data, default_columns, True, {'color': 'gray'}

    if n_clicks is not None and n_clicks > 0:
        return default_data, default_columns, True, {'color': 'gray', **default_cancel_button_style}

    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')
    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
    
    data = df.to_dict('records')
    columns = [{'name': col, 'id': col} for col in df.columns]

    # Check if data has been uploaded and change the color of the cancel button
    if len(data) > 1:
        cancel_button_style = {'color': 'black', **default_cancel_button_style}
    else:
        cancel_button_style = {'color': 'gray', **default_cancel_button_style}
    
    return data, columns, False, cancel_button_style



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=4000)
```

I am struggling for 2 days, no idea how to do it. I used the "data" from data-upload id and tried, but it is saying duplicate outputs so such errors, the code above has no error, just help me to add new callback for apply and clear buttons.

I really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.